# Amazon SES Statistics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, statistics

I facing some issue related to Amazon SES Statistic ordering, actually my recent sending mail static are in middle of data record it should be at top or lower of the record so what is the reason behind it?

My Question is How i do a simple report status with how much emails returned, invalid emails and emails sent if the "GetSendStatistics" returns a unordered list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to sort the data yourself, by using the `Timestamp` field of [`SendDataPoint`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SendDataPoint.html). Unfortunately, the list returning from `GetSendStatistics` is not sorted.

This happens because due to the characteristics and nature of sending e-mail over the Internet, it might take a different amount of time for a server to determine whether a message (or a set of messages) is confirmed to have bounced, or to be delivered for sure. Please refer to [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=222447) at AWS forums for a similar question and some insight into the issue you are facing.